# Playstation 5 Network Issues with Store and Now

Tags: networking, ps5

I have a launch Playstation 5 and when connected to wireless, or wired, it randomly cannot access anything on the store or Now. In so far as I can tell other things work and if you go to the network settings it shows everything connected and working.

A restart usually fixes it, or if I run a network test. I have an Xbox as well which encounters no issues and is in the same area.

I've been to the completely useless support site but no matter what sequences I try nothing gets me to the ability to chat with or email someone. My location is Canada.

Yes restarting is a solution but not something I ever had to do with the PS3 or PS4 Pro I had previously.

Ideas?